# Hide/show header in Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an event for when the user scrolls down the page, the header bar will be hidden, and when scrolling up the header will be displayed, and when reaching the top the header should always be present. However, the behavior is only working in Google Chrome, because in Google Chrome when you scroll down on the top, the page is updated, in Safari, Firefox, there is no such behavior. Could someone help me how to solve this?

[Header in safari/firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qh5z.png)
[Header in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thqMh.png)

```html
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  var banner = $('.site-header');
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
      banner.addClass('hide');
    } else {
      banner.removeClass('hide');
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: I checked your code. It works everywhere. It's just text, after all.

Comment: It turns out that in the Chrome Cast browser the behavior is correct. Because when you reach the top of the page, and perform the scroll up event, the page is updated (default chrome). However, in other browsers, when you reach the top of the page and scroll up, the page is not updated, it is only "stretched" and returns to the starting position. What happens is that the browser understands that the return is a scroll down and ends up hiding the div.